# Previous versions of Membase

Tags: membase

How do I download previous versions of Membase. I need 1.6.5.x.

The [downloads page](http://www.couchbase.com/downloads/membase-server/community) do not have links to previous builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this [page](http://www.openews.net/2011/membase-released-version-1-6-5/).

Alternatively, get the source from git (see [instructions](http://www.couchbase.com/wiki/display/couchbase/Architecture+and+Source+Repositories)) -- make sure you check out the version used to build the required Membase version (I'm not familiar with git, but [this page](https://github.com/membase/manifest/tree/master/released) might give you enough leads).